# How to set Ember environment variable of in qunit

Tags: ember.js, qunit

I am setting`ENV.HELPER_PARAM_LOOKUPS = true` for Ember.js so the linkTo helper will perform property look up instead of a hardcoded route. 
For example, I could do `{{linkTo view.path}}`

The way I set the environment variable is inside the  tag of my application.html.erb layout (I am using rails 4.0 by the way), as follow:

```
  <script type="text/javascript" >
  // Ember environment variable
      ENV = {
      HELPER_PARAM_LOOKUPS: true
      };
  </script>
```

However, when I run the qunit test, it gives error as:

> The attempt to linkTo route 'view.path.index' failed. The router did not find 'view.path.index' in its possible routes:

It also gives the deprecation warning:

> DEPRECATION: You provided a quoteless destination route parameter of view.path to the linkTo helper. Soon, this will perform a property lookup, rather than be treated as a string. To get rid of this warning, wrap view.path in quotes. To opt in to this new behavior, set ENV.HELPER_PARAM_LOOKUPS = true

Apparently, qunit is not configuring Ember.js as I intended. How to make qunit read my environment setting for ember when the test is loaded.

Here is the code in my qunit test:

```
module("Frontend Test", {
  setup: function() {
     Ember.run(App, App.advanceReadiness);
  },
  teardown: function() {
     App.reset();
  }
});

test("Check HTML is returned", function() {
  visit("/").then(function() {
ok(exists("*"), "Found HTML!");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is because you are declaring `ENV` after the import of the emberjs script.

If you are declaring before, using:

```
ENV = {
  HELPER_PARAM_LOOKUPS: true
};
```

this will work, but, after the ember script, you need to declare in the ember namespace:

```
Ember.ENV = {
  HELPER_PARAM_LOOKUPS: true
};
```

This is because, in initialization it does:

```
Ember.ENV = 'undefined' === typeof ENV ? {} : ENV;
```

and in `linkTo` helper, always uses the `Ember.ENV`:

```
if (Ember.ENV.HELPER_PARAM_LOOKUPS) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: Not only this is the correct answer, but also very quick answer! Thanks!
I was reading some other post which make me have the impression that the ENV have to be set before ember is loaded, that's why I place them in the <head> tag. But apparently, it could be set after Ember declaration, which makes more sense anyway.

Comment: You are welcome. I discovered this when hitting some problems in jsfiddle, because the code is load after emberjs import. So just ENV never worked for me, in that case.